# Tracking Salesforce Pardot Form Submits / Completions in DTM

Tags: forms, adobe, adobe-analytics

I have never had this issue before with normal forms however with trying to track form submits and even form completions from Salesforce Pardot forms Adobe analytics is always counting less form submits/completions then the Pardot platform. It is always very random sometimes 4% lower form submits then Pardot but can be as high as 50-60% at times on forms. The higher the total the bigger the discrepancy between the 2 platforms however Pardot always has more submits (and they are valid because they also contain the information from the user who filled out the form). So Adobe is somehow missing out on form submissions which I assume it may be because Pardot fires really fast at the top of the page and Adobe is slow and probably misses out on a number of form submits.

any help would be greatly appreciated

**Setup:**
My Adobe DTM / Adobe Analytics tool fires at page bottom and I am using a direct call rule to fire _satellite.track('form submit'); on the form button as form submission and also using an event based rule that looks for a datalayer object called with the string value "thank you page" that triggers a form complete.

[image]

[image: Adobe Analytics Tool]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you aren't using "Event Type --> submit" here?

Another suggestion that would probably help with the parody between Pardot and Adobe Analytics would be to fire the event on the "thank you" page (or completion) of the form instead of the click of submit.

There are many reasons you might see different numbers between 2 different systems on submit (Form errors on submit,etc.) so it's better to set the analytics event when you know the action is considered complete by Pardot.

Hope this helps.

Comment: event type> submit was the first thing I tried as that is what I was used to using however it was undercounting the submits as well when compared to pardot. We setup a thank you page and created a page load rule to fire however we also saw a big discrepancy to pardot.  We are going to create a very minimally coded pardot form and try again, we think that maybe some other code maybe responsible.

Comment: This is a classic case of 2 systems using different sets business rules to measure the same metric. I'm not sure you're ever going to get a match.I might suggest letting the business decide which is the system of record and go from there.

Comment: Not necessarily related, but per your code configuration screenshot, is there a good reason you are using custom app measurement code and creating another "s" object? This approach locks you out of any future Adobe code updates and can cause a ton of code inefficiencies with a large implementation.